# How to return an array of table records in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, array-agg

I am getting a type mismatch error when trying to return an array of elements of type `table1`, the inherent type of the `table1` I have declared.

```
Error occurred during SQL query execution

Razón:
 SQL Error [42P13]: ERROR: return type mismatch in function declared to return table1[]
  Detail: Actual return type is record[].
  Where: SQL function "arrayof_records"
```

This is an oversimplified code that reproduces my problem.

```sql
drop table if exists table1 cascade;

create table table1 (
  id        serial primary key,
  title     text,
  create_dt timestamp default now()
);

insert into table1 (title) values 
('one'),
('two'),
('three');

create or replace function arrayof_records ()
returns table1[]
stable language sql as $$
  select array_agg (t.*)
  from (
    select * from table1
    order by create_dt desc
  ) as t;
$$;
```

It is clear that the parser is expecting some other expression in the `array_agg` function. I have tried  `t`, `t.*` and `*`. All of them fail.

I expect there is a syntax, as PostgreSQL 12 documentations states "array_agg(expression)|any non-array type".

Any idea?

Comment: `array_agg(t)`? But why return an array? Why not use `returns setof table1`?

Comment: No, I tested that: `Error occurred during SQL query execution

Razón:
 SQL Error [42P13]: ERROR: return type mismatch in function declared to return table1[]
  Detail: Actual return type is record[].
  Where: SQL function "arrayof_records"``

Comment: Seems that I have to type cast?

Comment: Right: t::table1

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a slightly different way of creating the array:

```
create or replace function arrayof_records ()
  returns table1[]
  stable language sql 
as 
$$
  select array(
    select table1 
    from table1
    order by create_dt desc
  );
$$;
```

That's typically faster than array_agg() as well.

Comment: Thanks, speed is important to me.